# how to save diff between text files as image or PDF

Tags: image, pdf, diff

I need to save diff of two text files(and two folders with subfolders with text files) as image, or pdf.
I have read tortoisesvn and kdiff3 docs to find such info, but I have not found info about it.
Is it any tool, which could do it? Also it would be perfect, if tool will contain some couple of option, for example:

1. if I create diff for two folders I would like to get one diff image for all files, or one diff file for each item in folder
2. change colors of diff
3. create diff with full content of files, or set number of lines, which would be shown before and after different places